# codedeploy unable to access s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-codepipeline, aws-code-deploy

[image]I have a codepipeline on **Account A** and codedeployment group on **Account B**. I'm seeing the below error once the codedeployment group start the trigger
`The IAM role arn:aws:iam::accountb:role/testcrss does not give you permission to perform operations in the following AWS service: Amazon S3. Contact your AWS administrator if you need help. If you are an AWS administrator, you can grant permissions to your users or groups by creating IAM policies.`

I was referring to this [document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/pipelines-create-cross-account.html) provided by aws for aws cross-account deployment using codepipeline, do I need to configure anything other than the info provided in the document?

**policies attached to testcrss role**

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:Get*",
                "s3:List*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "kms:DescribeKey",
                "kms:GenerateDataKey*",
                "kms:Encrypt",
                "kms:ReEncrypt*",
                "kms:Decrypt"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:kms:us-east-2:AccountA:key/valuetest"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:Get*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::AccountA bucket/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::AccountA bucket"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**Bucket policy on Account A**

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "SSEAndSSLPolicy",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "DenyUnEncryptedObjectUploads",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::AccountAbucket/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotEquals": {
                    "s3:x-amz-server-side-encryption": "aws:kms"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "DenyInsecureConnections",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::AccountAbucket/*",
            "Condition": {
                "Bool": {
                    "aws:SecureTransport": "false"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::AccountB:root"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:Get*",
                "s3:Put*"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::AccountAbucket/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::AccountB:root"
            },
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::AccountAbucket"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Cross-account permissions",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::AccountB:role/testcrss"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:Get*",
                "s3:List*"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::AccountAbucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Trust Relationship for Role testcrss**

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": [
          "codedeploy.amazonaws.com",
          "ec2.amazonaws.com"
        ]
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Please include the document

Comment: @ChrisWilliams Added

Comment: It seems that either `testcrss` and/or instance role have no permissions for s3 to execute the deployment. Can you post the role and instance profile?

Comment: @Marcin Edited the question with  policy json

Comment: Does the bucket policy in Acc A allow access from Acc B?

Comment: @Marcin Yes, added bucket policy to grant access to Account B, modified question with bucket policy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was the KMS key which was added to **Account B** was incorrect, this key is required to access the s3 bucket on **Account A**.
KMS key should be the same as the KMS key attached to the codepipeline on **Account A**